# Can I use C# code to add a call to a command instead of a <Grid.GestureRecognizers>?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
<ViewCell x:Name="co">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OpenPickerCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference coPicker}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
      </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
      <Picker x:Name="coPicker" IsVisible="false" HorizontalOptions="End" SelectedIndexChanged="coPickerSelectedIndexChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Order}"></Picker>
      <Label x:Name="coLabel" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Is there a way that I can in C# connect up a command to the tapping of the cell rather than have to use the XAML `<Grid.GestureRecognizers>` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a `GestureRecognizer` to a `ViewCell` is a big no-no. A `ViewCell` exists within a ListView or TableView which have more than enough tapped options of their own. Adding a `GestureRecognizer` might confuse the OS as to which tap it should handle.

***Your options for the `GestureRecognizer` are basically the following 3, but I advise against them in a scenario where you have a `ListView`/`TableView`.***

Check out some of the ListView/ViewCell based alternatives I mention below in your situation.

---

**1. GestureRecognizer - Add it in code**

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    // handle the tap
};
myGrid.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

**2. GestureRecognizer - Use a command**

When you use MVVM you can also use a command binding in C#:

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding (TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, "TapCommand");
myGrid.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

Which can then be bound in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
</Grid>
```

**3. GestureRecognizer - Add it in XAML as you have done**

```
<Grid>
      <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OpenPickerCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference coPicker}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
      </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
</Grid>
```

---

**4. ViewCell - Tapped event**

For the `ViewCell` you have a `Tapped` event:

```
<ViewCell Height="100" Tapped="OnTapped">
    <ViewCell.View>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" >
        </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

Which you can implement in code-behind:

```
void OnTapped (object sender, System.EventArgs e) { //your code}
```

**5. ViewCell - Tapped command**

When using MVVM you don't want to put a lot of business logic in the code-behind for your pages. In that case you can use a `Behavior` to convert the event to a command. A sample of that can be found here:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior/EventToCommandBehavior

---

**6. ListView - ItemSelected**

`ListView` itself also has an `ItemSelected` event. This can be handled the same way as the `ViewCell` `Tapped` event with both an event in code-behind or a `Behavior` to delegate it to a `Command`.

**7. ListView - SelectedItem property**

You can bind the `SelectedItem` to a property in your view model. On the setter you can perform your custom code.

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" >
</ListView>
```

And in code:

```
string _yourSelectedItem;
public string YourSelectedItem
{
    get { return _yourSelectedItem; }
    set {
        _yourSelectedItem = value;
        // Perform your custom functionality
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer.  I appreciate all the effort you put into the suggestions.  Based on your answer I think perhaps the most easy for me to implement would be to use the Tapped event.  In my situation I use a picker so I will open up a new question now as I am not quite sure how to implement that with onTapped. Thanks