# How can I make the Tapped event of a ViewCell send a param to a generic function and then open up a picker for that ViewCell element?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Update:**  Just a reminder,  there's a 500 point bonus on this if someone can just show me how to implement this functionality without using Gestures>

I am using a ViewCell and a gesture recognizer to open up a picker with the following code. The ViewCell has a label on the left and a label area on the right that is populated initially when the app starts and later with the picker when the ViewCell is clicked.

**XAML**

```xml
<ViewCell x:Name="ati" Tapped="OpenPickerCommand">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer 
             Command="{Binding OpenPickerCommand}" 
             CommandParameter="{x:Reference atiPicker}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
      </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
      <local:LabelBodyRendererClass Text="Answer Time Interval" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <Picker x:Name="atiPicker" IsVisible="false" HorizontalOptions="End" SelectedIndexChanged="atiPickerSelectedIndexChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Times}"></Picker>
      <local:LabelBodyRendererClass x:Name="atiLabel" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>

<ViewCell x:Name="pti" Tapped="OpenPickerCommand">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer 
             Command="{Binding OpenPickerCommand}" 
             CommandParameter="{x:Reference ptiPicker}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
      </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
      <local:LabelBodyRendererClass Text="Phrase Time Interval" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <Picker x:Name="ptiPicker" IsVisible="false" HorizontalOptions="End" SelectedIndexChanged="ptiPickerSelectedIndexChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Times}"></Picker>
      <local:LabelBodyRendererClass x:Name="ptiLabel" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

**C#** This works for different pickers (ati, bti, pti etc) with CommandParameter

```cs
public SettingsPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   BindingContext = new CommandViewModel();
}

void atiPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (Picker)sender;
        int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex != -1)
        {
            App.DB.UpdateIntSetting(Settings.Ati, selectedIndex);
            atiLabel.Text = AS.ati.Text();
        }
    }

void ptiPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (Picker)sender;
        int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex != -1)
        {
            App.DB.UpdateIntSetting(Settings.Pti, selectedIndex);
            ptiLabel.Text = AS.pti.Text();
        }
    }


public class CommandViewModel: ObservableProperty
{
    public ICommand openPickerCommand;

    public CommandViewModel()
    {
        openPickerCommand = new Command<Picker>(PickerFocus);
        //openPickerCommand = new Command(tapped);
    }

    public ICommand OpenPickerCommand
    {
        get { return openPickerCommand; }
    }

    void PickerFocus(Picker param)
    {
        param.Focus();
    }
}
```

I would like to remove the use of TapGestureRecognizers but I still want to retain the functionality and layout.

It's been suggested to me that it would be better if I used the Tapped event of the ViewCell like this:

```
 Tapped="OnTapped"
```

Can someone explain in some detail how I could wire this up in C#.  Would I be best to code something into the CommandViewModel as well as in the C# backing code. Also can the view model have one method that takes an argument so it could be used to open up different pickers?

An example of how I could do this would be very much appreciated. Note that I don't particularly need to use the CommandViewModel if there is a way that I could do this by coding just in the .cs backing code.

Comment: you got so detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366457/can-i-use-c-sharp-code-to-add-a-call-to-a-command-instead-of-a-grid-gesturereco what else you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @Samantha J! Can you share the C# Code-Behind for the ViewCell classes?

Comment: I already shared all of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Sorry for the poor english)

Despite not being best practice, I guess you can do something like this, dismissing the viewmodel:

**XAML:**

```xml
<ViewCell x:Name="ati" Tapped="OpenPickerCommand">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <local:LabelBodyRendererClass Text="Answer Time Interval" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <Picker x:Name="atiPicker" 
              IsVisible="false" 
              HorizontalOptions="End" 
              SelectedIndexChanged="atiPickerSelectedIndexChanged" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Times}">
      </Picker>
      <local:LabelBodyRendererClass x:Name="atiLabel" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>

<ViewCell x:Name="pti" Tapped="OpenPickerCommand">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <local:LabelBodyRendererClass Text="Phrase Time Interval" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <Picker x:Name="ptiPicker" IsVisible="false" HorizontalOptions="End" SelectedIndexChanged="ptiPickerSelectedIndexChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Times}"></Picker>
      <local:LabelBodyRendererClass x:Name="ptiLabel" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

**C#:**

```cs
private void OpenPickerCommand(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        Picker pkr = sender == ati ? atiPicker : ptiPicker;
        pkr.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answering your question "Can the view model have one method that takes an argument?", it is exactly what you're already doing using the 'OpenPickerCommand' method. The problem is that using the ViewCell's public event 'Tapped', you can't set parameters to the delegate handler.

Let me know if it works for you or if you do need some more information.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with attached properties. Simply define a "*behavior*" class for ViewCell that adds the Command/Parameter properties.

```cs
public static class TappedCommandViewCell
{
    private const string TappedCommand = "TappedCommand";
    private const string TappedCommandParameter = "TappedCommandParameter";

    public static readonly BindableProperty TappedCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
            TappedCommand,
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(TappedCommandViewCell),
            default(ICommand),
            BindingMode.OneWay,
            null,
            PropertyChanged);

    public static readonly BindableProperty TappedCommandParameterProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
            TappedCommandParameter,
            typeof(object),
            typeof(TappedCommandViewCell),
            default(object),
            BindingMode.OneWay,
            null);

    private static void PropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (bindable is ViewCell cell)
        {
            cell.Tapped -= ViewCellOnTapped;
            cell.Tapped += ViewCellOnTapped;
        }
    }

    private static void ViewCellOnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ViewCell cell && cell.IsEnabled)
        {
            var command = GetTappedCommand(cell);
            var parameter = GetTappedCommandParameter(cell);

            if (command != null && command.CanExecute(parameter))
            {
                command.Execute(parameter);
            }
        }
    }

    public static ICommand GetTappedCommand(BindableObject bindableObject) =>
        (ICommand)bindableObject.GetValue(TappedCommandProperty);

    public static void SetTappedCommand(BindableObject bindableObject, object value) =>
        bindableObject.SetValue(TappedCommandProperty, value);

    public static object GetTappedCommandParameter(BindableObject bindableObject) =>
        bindableObject.GetValue(TappedCommandParameterProperty);

    public static void SetTappedCommandParameter(BindableObject bindableObject, object value) =>
        bindableObject.SetValue(TappedCommandParameterProperty, value);
}
```

After that reference your behavior namespace in XAML and specify the property values using fully qualified names:

```xml
<ViewCell StyleId="disclosure-indicator"
          behaviors:TappedCommandViewCell.TappedCommand="{Binding BrowseCommand}"
          behaviors:TappedCommandViewCell.TappedCommandParameter="https://www.google.com">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Recipient"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               Margin="20,0"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding LedgerRecord.Recipient}"
               HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

The above will allow you to use MVVM and no Tap Gesture Recognizers.

Answer (score 1):

- The first problem is that you're mixing the code-behind and MVVM
  approaches in the same code. It is confusing and certainly not the
  right way to code what you want to achieve. So, all commanding must
  be in the ViewModel attached to the View, no code-behind apart some
  code only used for UI effects.

  - There is no need to define a gesture recognizer for all visual items since you just want to detect the tap on all the surface of the viewcell. To achieve this you must define all children of the ViewCell with InputTransparent=true. So the tap will not be detected and will be trapped by the parent ViewCell (you
    must indicate the InpuTransparent because there is no tap event
    bubbling in X.Forms).
  - Showing and Hidding the picker is a View problem not a ViewModel one. So here you can use some code-behind to create an event handler for the ViewCell Tapped event. This handler will just set visible=true on the picker.
  - The picker selected event must be connected to a corresponding Command in the ViewModel. So each time the picker is displayed and a value is selected your viewmodel will be aware of the action. This is the only command you need in your viewmodel. Depending of XForms version the picker has no bindable command, so you can use one of the numerous "bindablepicker" implementation you can find on the web or you can also use a XAML EventToCommand Behavior.

So there is two different problems : showing/hidding the picker which can be achieved directly in XAML or with the help of a bit of code-behind; and the picker item selection that must be managed using a Command in the viewmodel.

Hoping this will help you

Comment: Thanks Olivier,  Can you provide an example of what you mean using the code that I have for my app?

Comment: Link to download the Gif that shows the effect : ![SamDemo.Gif](http://www.e-naxos.com/download/samdemo.gif)

Comment: Link to download the full demo source code : ![Demo Project Zip(http://www.e-naxos.com/download/Demo4Sam.zip)

Comment: You'll see all the things I talk about in my fist post. The project run with VS2017. It is using Prism for Xamarin Forms has MVVM support lib but you can use what you want, this is not important in the demo and you'll understand easily if you know MVVM pattern. Feel free to ask for explanations. Have a nice day !